# Infer Generic Type In Completion Block

Tags: swift

I have a function:

```
static func requestArray<T>(completion: @escaping (_ result: Result<[T], Error>) -> ()) {

}
```

That is called like this:

```
MyClass.requestArray() { result in
    switch result {
        case .success(let array):
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            break
        }
}
```

However, this doesn't work because it can't infer the generic type T. How can I alter my code so that it does recognise what type T should be? (Assume `array` should be of type `[String]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have explicitly declare the type of `result` in the completion handler when you call the function:

```
MyClass.requestArray() { (result: Result<[String], Error>) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let array):
        break
    case .failure(let error):
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's generally more convenient if the API moves the type into the signature, in order to simplify the closure:

```
static func requestArray<T>(of: T.Type, completion: @escaping (_ result: Result<[T], Error>) -> ()) { }
```

When done this way, the call becomes:

```
MyClass.requestArray(of: String.self) { result in
    switch result {
        case .success(let array):
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            break
        }
}
```

This approach also works nicely when `T` is a return type. See `Codeable` for a good example of this approach in methods like `decode(_;from:)`.

Comment: You can also make the parameter `of: T.Type? = nil` which allows you to specify the type in either way.